# Use hook to remove height from img tag?

Tags: 7, hooks

The theme I am building is responsive and so many images have `max-width:100%;` applied in CSS. Can I use a hook in *template.php* to strip the height attribute from `img` tags because it is causing lots of distortion issues, and how would I go about this?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your images are being built by `theme('image',...)` you can override its default...

```
function theme_image($variables) {
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];
  $attributes['src'] = file_create_url($variables['path']);

  foreach (array('width', 'height', 'alt', 'title') as $key) {

    if (isset($variables[$key])) {
      $attributes[$key] = $variables[$key];
    }
  }

  return '<img' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />';
```

}

...in your template.php file along the lines of this:

```
function YOURTHEME_image($variables) {
  $attributes = $variables['attributes'];
  $attributes['src'] = file_create_url($variables['path']);

  foreach (array('alt', 'title') as $key) {

    if (isset($variables[$key])) {
      $attributes[$key] = $variables[$key];
    }
  }

  return '<img' . drupal_attributes($attributes) . ' />';
```

}

and now those pesky `height=`s and `width=`s should be gone.

Comment: just flush caches after doing this to make sure the theme registry is rebuilt and it sees it

Answer (score 0):

Rather than editing Drupal behavior can also just set `img` CSS to `height:auto`